# How to edit the url in current browser using Watin

Tags: watin

I need to navigate to new url from the current opened browser using Wating Code, Let me know if any one tried the same scenario. Also I need to get the url in the current opened browser.

Answer (score 3):

```
using (IE browser = new IE())
{
    browser.GoTo("www.google.co.uk");
    string curentUrl = browser.Url;
}
```

If the browser is already open, you use the AttachTo static method

http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html

HTH!